# Android client-server app - readLine() does't work

Tags: java, android, client-server

I'm writing an a client(android)-server(java) app based on Socket. My problem is that I need to handle two types of message on server (MINDWAVE and SPHERO). The mindwave message is well processed by server but I've got a problem with the sphero one:
-client sends the message "SPHERO" to sever.
-server prints "Sphero request catched." and goes through the rest of its code fine
-client stucks on its "while((fromServer = in.readLine())!=null)" loop (it doesn't even start the loop's first operation - just stucks on readline() part).

The client's thread

```
class SendSpheroRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String fromServer = "";
    int movement;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (isActive) {
            try {
                socket = new Socket(address, port);
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

                out.write(TAG);
                out.flush();
                out.close();

                socket = new Socket(address, port);
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        socket.getInputStream()));
                while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), fromServer,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (!fromServer.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                        try {
                            movement = Integer.parseInt(fromServer);

                            if (movement > 0) {
                                driveUp();
                            } else if (movement < 0) {
                                driveDown();
                            }
                            tvPosition.setText(movement + "");
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            movement = 0;
                        }
                        fromServer = "";
                    }
                }

                Thread.sleep(1000);

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

And the server's message handling:

```
public void processMessage(String message) {
    Message messageObject = new Message(message);

    if (messageObject.getClientType() == DEVICE_TYPE.MINDWAVE) {
        System.out.println("Message sent by "
                + messageObject.getClientType() + " with ID="
                + messageObject.getClientID() + ". The attention value is "
                + messageObject.getAttention());
        switch (messageObject.getClientID()) {
        case 1: {
            if (firstClientIterator < 5 && gameStarted
                    && messageObject.getAttention() != 0) {
                firstClientAttentionSum += messageObject.getAttention();
                firstClientIterator++;
                System.out.println("sum=" + firstClientAttentionSum
                        + " iterator=" + firstClientIterator);
            }
        }
            break;
        case 2: {
            if (secondClientIterator < 5 && gameStarted
                    && messageObject.getAttention() != 0) {
                secondClientAttentionSum += messageObject.getAttention();
                secondClientIterator++;
                System.out.println("sum=" + secondClientAttentionSum
                        + " iterator=" + secondClientIterator);
            }
        }
            break;
        default:
            System.err
                    .println("Cannot process the message. Hint: wrong id detected.");
        }
    } else if (messageObject.getClientType() == DEVICE_TYPE.SPHERO) {
        System.out.println("Sphero request catched.");
        try {
            toClientPrintWriter = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            if (firstClientIterator == 5 && secondClientIterator == 5) {
                int difference = firstClientAttentionSum
                        - secondClientAttentionSum;
                System.out.println("Sending data to Sphero. "
                        + "The difference is " + difference + ".");
                firstClientIterator = secondClientIterator = firstClientAttentionSum = secondClientAttentionSum = 0;
                toClientPrintWriter.println(difference+"");

            } else {
                toClientPrintWriter.println("No results yet.");
            }
            toClientPrintWriter.flush();
            toClientPrintWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why the sleeps? They are literally a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

`readLine()` only returns when it reads a newline or when the stream closes. So you should send `"SPHERO\n"`.